# Wordpress Forward/back through certain number of posts on main page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

My blog at [Dark Moon In Orbit](http://sparkygetsthegirl.com/blog/) is being upgraded (by me). On single post pages, I can scroll to the next or previous link. On the archive pages, I can also do this (I think at 10 posts a page). I want to be able to do this on the main page, where 3 posts are shown in 3 columns. So i want to show the next three, and the next, and so on, on my front page. I cut and pasted the code from the archive.php file to do this into my home.php (which I have confirmed is what gets loaded on my blog's front page).

Here is the code:

```
    <?php
    if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
        $count = 0;
        while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
            // Account for sticky posts by ignoring any posts over our desired number of three at a time.
            if ( $count > 2 )
            {
                continue;
            }

            $count++;
?>
    <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <p class="postmetadata"><?php the_tags( '', __( ', ', 'depo-masthead' ), '<br />' ); ?></p>
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf( __( 'Permanent Link to %s', 'depo-masthead' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <small><?php printf( __( 'In %1$s on %2$s at %3$s', 'depo-masthead' ), get_the_category_list( __( ', ', 'depo-masthead' ) ), '<strong>' . get_the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ) . '</strong>', '<strong>' . get_the_time() . '</strong>' ); ?></small>

            <div class="entry">
                <?php the_content('[…]')  ?>
                <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit this entry.', 'depo-masthead' ), '<p>', '</p>' ); ?>
                    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <h2 class="center"><?php _e( 'Not Found', 'depo-masthead' ); ?></h2>
    <p class="center"><?php _e( "Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.", 'depo-masthead' ); ?></p>
    <?php get_search_form(); ?>

       <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="previous">
                <?php previous_posts_link( '<span class="arrow">&laquo;</span> <span class="link"><span class="before">' . __( 'Newer', 'depo-masthead' ) . '</span><span class="title">' . __( 'Entries', 'depo-masthead' ) . '</span></span>' ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="next">
                <?php next_posts_link( '<span class="link"><span class="after">' . __( 'Older', 'depo-masthead' ) . '</span><span class="title">' . __( 'Entries', 'depo-masthead' ) . '</span></span> <span class="arrow">&raquo;</span>' ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I cut out some of the unnecessary code in the middle (just for display purposes) and left the loop. There are a few issues here:
1. The count variable seems to be ignored. if I remove this, it still only shows 3 posts for the main page. But if I output the number of posts with the WP variable, I get 46. The number of posts per a page is set at 10 in my theme, so this is very strange.

1. When I click 'Entries Older' it does show the *next* 3 posts, but then does not change to reflect that you can go back to the previous posts, nor does it go to the next 3 when I click 'Entries Older' again.

This is very frustrating. Any ideas to help?

EDITED: I also found that when you click the 'Older Entries' arrow, the web address changes to http://sparkygetsthegirl.com/blog/page/2/

If you manually change the '2' above to '3', it *does* show the next 3 entries. So internally it's all working, but for some reason the previous_posts_link and next_posts_link isn't working.

Comment: You have already set `query_posts('post_per_page=3');` on the top.

Comment: *lol* Sorry, ignore that part. I added that in as a test (changing the amount didn't affect the result) and forgot to clear it up. Even without that, I get the same.

Comment: Check out in `settings->reading` section for `Blog pages show at most`

Comment: As indicated above, it's set to '10'. If you click on 'Archive->Fiction' in my menu, it shows up to 10 posts there.